# How to execute a bash script when my systemd service crashes?

Tags: linux, systemd

I'm using a systemd service. I want to execute a bash script when my systemd service goes down -- fails. I don't want to execute a bash script when I restart the service myself. But only when it or the process it supervices crashes by itself.

How can I do that? Should I use `OnFailure`? Or `ExecStopPost`?

Note that in my systemd service there's only `ExecStart` and no `ExecStop`

Answer (score 0):

From what i could find on https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=169344 , using `OnFailure=` should be sufficient.
It will run when the exit code of your service is non-zero.
 Although, I found no mention of this in the sytemd.service manpage.